# Why is my recursive dfs function returning the wrong value?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Trying to do a leetcode problem but Im stuck on this one tree question. https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-univalue-path/

My solution doesn't work for the below test case but I tried to debug it and couldnt figure out why. When I go over it, I get the correct answer in my code. Hoping someone can tell me what Ive done wrong. Thank you
Below is the test case it fails and my code in Java

```
[5,4,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,null,null,null,4,null,null,4,null,null,4,null,4,4,null,null,4,4]
```

```
class Solution {
    int longestPath = 0;
    public int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode root) {
        dfs(root, root.val);
        
        return longestPath ;
    }
    
        public int dfs(TreeNode root, int value){
        if(root == null) return 0;
        
        int leftPath = dfs(root.left, root.val);
        int rightPath = dfs(root.right, root.val);
        
        longestPath = Math.max(longestPath, leftPath + rightPath);
        
        int val = (root.val == value) ? 1 : 0;
        return Math.max(leftPath, rightPath) + val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Looks good!

The return condition has to be modified. This'll pass:

```
class Solution {
    int longestPath = 0;
    public int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        dfs(root, root.val);

        return longestPath ;
    }

    public int dfs(TreeNode root, int value) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int leftPath = dfs(root.left, root.val);
        int rightPath = dfs(root.right, root.val);

        longestPath = Math.max(longestPath, leftPath + rightPath);

        return root.val == value ? 1 + Math.max(leftPath, rightPath) : 0;
    }
}
```